# What's a good GUI utility to apply patches on Windows?

Tags: windows, diff, patch, utility

I'm looking for a good GUI patch utility for Windows - this is something that I'll be sending to someone who hasn't worked with patches much before, so ease of use is important. I know WinMerge can generate patches, but it can't apply them; does such a GUI utility exist for Windows?

PS - I considered posting this to superuser, but since diff/patch are primarily programming tools, I thought it would be better suited here. If there's consensus otherwise, I'll vote to migrate myself.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear he means .patch files as created by the `diff` command (or other version control systems).

Comment: Exactly; ordinary unified-diff files.

Comment: @ewall It might be clear to you, but there are a vast number of other kinds of patch out there.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth -- oh, agreed. That was my question at first until I noticed that 'diff' was in the tags and the postscript line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TortoiseMerge](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/TortoiseMerge.html), which is found in [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/), [TortoiseCVS](http://www.tortoisecvs.org/), or [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) will fit the bill. However, be warned that the full installation adds other right-click menu options by default, so the user may prefer to custom-install just the piece(s) they want.

Comment: TortoiseMerge will not work without a working copy of the repo. Any GUI for doing that for file systems not under source control?

Comment: @IneQuation Er, nope... TortoiseMerge works fine on standalone files/directories on my office PC. Of course, there are [a zillion other options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools) too. [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) is maybe one of the most popular, but I've not used it so can't comment.

Comment: Interesting, because when trying to apply patches to stand-alone directories, I'm getting a message that "directory x is not a working copy" and the program denies any action. Diffing does work. My copy comes from Tortoise SVN, maybe those others don't have this restriction?

Comment: Ah, could be -- the version I have installed currently is TortoiseGit. Perhaps they've customized the TortoiseMerge versions so they differ across the different VCSes?